# How can I add multiple taps to a button or a UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I want one of my screens to be accessed only if the user taps three times on a button within a second. eg. if there's a button on View controller A, a user should tap 3 times within a second on that button to get to View Controller B. 
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add tap gesture recogniser to your custom View.

```
-(void)handleTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGestureRecognizer{

    NSLog(@"3 tapped");
   //add code to present another View Controller

}


-(void)buttonView{
  UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapGesture:)];
tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired=3;
[self.customButtonView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];

  }
```

**Swift:**

```
    func handleTapGesture(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    NSLog("3 tapped")
    //add code to present another View Controller
}



    func buttonView() {
    var tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTapGesture:")
    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 3
    self.customButtonView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
}
```

You can call this method in `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: @Mr.T thanks for the answer, it will be helpful if the code is in swift. Also I want those taps to be performed within a second so i need some kind of timer too.

Comment: are you delaying the each tap ? normally 3 taps would take 0.2-0.5 seconds. If that is the case, there is no need of timer

Answer (score 0):

Buttons are not set up to respond to multiple taps. You'll have to simulate that yourself.

As others have said, you can create a tap gesture recognizer and attach it to any view. For some views you'll need to set the userInteractionEnabled flag to true before it will respond though.

If you want a button to handle double-taps you'll need to have the button with no action installed but a 2 click gesture recognizer attached.